# How to remove the first few and last few elements in an array and keep the remainder

Tags: javascript, arrays

Been looking at [arr.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) but that does not seem to be what I'm after. Basically, I need to "splice" a range, ie:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

I need to return a new array with either:

```
const newA = [1,2,3]
const newB = [4,5,6]
const newC = [7,8,9]
```

Surely arr.splice() can achieve the first and last but how to achieve something like `newB`?

In plain english, "remove the first `n` index and also the `n` last index in the array (`arr`) and give me the rest" which should be `newB`.

Comment: Does that help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357805/how-to-delete-the-last-element-from-an-array-java
and that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663944/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-the-first-element-from-an-array

Comment: I have no knowledge of Java, sorry.

Comment: Related [add and remove specific array elements using array.splice()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419025/add-and-remove-specific-array-elements-using-array-splice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yopu want [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) not splice (if you want to do it in a single call).

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].slice(3, 6));
```

Also, slice returns a new array, splice just changes the original.

---

To clear up any ambiguity..

If you want to remove the last `n` items and the first `y` items, you might consider defining this function..

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const newA = arrayTrim(a, 0, 7);
const newB = arrayTrim(a, 3, 4)
const newC = arrayTrim(a, 6, 1);

console.log(newA, newB, newC);

function arrayTrim(array, first=0, last=0){
  last = !last ? undefined : -last;
  return array.slice(first, last)
}
```

If you want to start at the `n`th index and get `y` items from the array you can use this..

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const newA = arrayTrim(a, 0, 3);
const newB = arrayTrim(a, 3, 3)
const newC = arrayTrim(a, 6, 3)

console.log(newA, newB, newC);

function arrayTrim(array, first, length){
  return array.slice(first, length+first)
}
```

Comment: You should use `3, -3`, since he wants the between, whatever length that is.

Comment: @zfrisch - not according to his exampes he doesn't. using -3 would return 3-7 while his example is 3-6...

Comment: I would ask the OP but he states `In plain english, "remove the first n index and also the n last index in the array (arr) and give me the rest" which should be newB.`

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. `slice()` is not the only approach available to achieve the requirement using a single call https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346486/how-to-remove-the-first-few-and-last-few-elements-in-an-array-and-keep-the-remai/48346529#comment83679008_48346529

Comment: Yep, I just realized my mistake haha. I kept thinking about it like `.splice`. oi vey, sorry.

Comment: At second example `.slice(0, 0)` returns an empty array

Comment: @guest271314 - i thought you were being sarcastic when you added that comment... even so, that would require op to know exactly which indexes he wanted... it sounds like he wanted to simply trim the first and lest few off, which means he would have to calculate which indexes he wanted to keep and at that point it;s more than one call... i'll edit the function to account for zeros though, thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. The function is currently defined with default parameters set to `0`, where `const newA = arrayTrim(a) // []`

Answer (score 3):

```
arr.splice(0, 3);
arr.splice(-4); // or arr.splice(6)
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Alternatively  `Object.assign(arr, {length:3, 0:arr[3], 1:arr[4], 2:arr[5]})`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use two arguments for `arr.slice`

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

arr.slice(0,3); /*returns [1,2,3]*/
arr.slice(3,7); /*returns [4,5,6,7]*/
arr.slice(7,10); /*returns [8,9,10]*/
```